# Cordova : Build error gradle for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build

This is my first time with Cordova and I want to do my first **Hello World** on Android Device ... but, when I build my app with :

```
cordova build
```

It compiles until I get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug.
>com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.graddle.process.internal.ExecException:
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

BUILD FAILED
```

I test some solution like put this in my build.gradle but without sucess :

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true // add
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Also, I try to clean my project with 'clean.bat' of Cordova and to rebuild it but I get the same error message !

Maybe it's some permission to put in the AndroidManifest ? Any clue ?

Note :  I update the distributionURL in the GradleBuilder.js file like this

```
var distributionUrl = '../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, ... BUILD SUCCESSFUL !

I just install an other version of [JDK (version 8u92)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and change my environment variable JAVA_HOME to the new location.

You clean the project and when you build it again, it's working ;)

Comment: Then your answer is right, not mine So you can change the right mark from my to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest try adding the MultiDexApplication class

```
<application ...
     android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

**Also Update your build.gradle file with**

```
android{

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to add his after cleaning my project but nothing change, same error !

Comment: I got an issue in ionic build.. I just changed `multiDexEnabled true` works fine to me.

Comment: Glad to here this, you can upvote my answer it will help others too

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the android sdk path (`F:\sdksdk\android-sdk-windows`) and the platform-tools path (`F:\sdksdk\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools`) and tools path (`F:\sdksdk\android-sdk-windows\tools`) in environment variable.

You should add a new item named ANDROID_HOME the value is sdk path (`F:\sdksdk\android-sdk-windows`). And add platform-tools path and tools path to path.